# How many X fit into Y?

Tags: c#, math

Given two numbers `X` and `Y`, how can I compute how many `X`'s can fit into `Y`?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more information as to what "cleanest" means and how efficient is "most efficient". Without any context, the answer is easy...

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using division for this? I mean, that's what division does. Why is that not clean and efficient?

Comment: Why is it assumed 16 and 12345 are integers or floats? Numbers can be implemented as strings. Furthermore, the meaning of "fitting into" is underspecified.

Comment: if it were a float it would be 16.0, and its obvious its not a string otherwise that would have been mentioned.. question was simple enough don't get why you all trolling at it.. Didn't think division would work, because thought if it had a remainder it wouldn't be an int anymore newbie mistake i am sorry.. didn't realize a cast was all that was needed..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good old division to the rescue!

```
float x = 16;
float y = 12345;
float howMany = ((float)y)/x;  //> 771.5625
int floor = (int)howMany;      //> 771
int ceil = (int)(howMany+0.5f);//> 772
```

---

Alliteratively, since you leave us guessing, you may want:

```
int lenX = "16".Length;
int lenY = "12345".Length;
float howMany = (float)lenY/lenX; //> 2.5
```

Comment: That simple.. so if the number was 31 and obvious 16 only goes into this once it wouldn't round it up to 2? Ps. a lot of negative votes on this.. thats all people ever seem to do anymore..

Comment: the actual value is 1.9375, so if you want 1 you could do `(int)howMany`. If you want it to round up you can do `(int)(howMany+0.5f)` :)

Comment: Note also, that you can use `Math.Floor` and `Math.Ceiling` functions to get the same as `floor` and `ceil`.

Comment: Excellent will mark you as answer when it lets me. And for everyone else you wonder why people never vote you up its cause you vote newbies down and we need rep to actually give you ups! yes turned out to be a simple answer but I thought Id have to use modulus and loops..

Comment: @ravenx30 Your question is fine. It's an extremely fundamental one, and I can't find a duplicate on Stack Overflow. If you were to put some more effort into nicely wording and formatting your question, it would generally be better-received.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways your question could be interpreted.

## (1) How many *fractional* `X`'s can fit into `Y`?

In mathematics, the answer to this question is `Y / X`. In a programming language, if `X` and `Y` are integer values, you'll have to take care to cast them to floating point values before performing the division.

#### When `X` and `Y` are integers

```
int X = 5;
int Y = 17;
double N = (double)Y / (double)X;
// N is 3.4
```

#### When `X` and `Y` are real numbers

```
double X = 2.5;
double Y = 11.5;
double N = Y / X;
// N is 4.6
```

## (2) How many *whole* `X`'s can fit into `Y`?

In mathematics, the answer to this question is `⌊Y / X⌋`, the floor of `Y` divided by `X`. In a programming language, if `X` and `Y` are integer values, the `/` operator applied to them will typically perform *integer division*. Integer division discards the remainder of division, so you don't have to call any `floor` function.

#### When `X` and `Y` are integers

```
int X = 5;
int Y = 17;
int N = Y / X;
// N is 3
```

#### When `X` and `Y` are real numbers

```
double X = 2.5;
double Y = 11.5;
int N = (int)Math.Floor(Y / X);
// N is 4
```